# Getting values from dynamic tags from XML

Tags: r, xml

I have data like:

```
<location country="SWITZERLAND" city="" state="" xsi:nil="true"/>
<location country="URUGUAY" city="" state="" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Above locations tag is of dynamic size in the XML, I have shown 2 countries only, but it could be 1 or 5 also. Now I want to extract the values like `SWITZERLAND`,  `URUGUAY`, and store them in a single cell of the dataframe.

Comment: Look up regular expressions. You can use them to extract the required text. Then use `paste` to concatenate them

Comment: @Rohit no, regex is not the tool to be used here. See Prem's answer.

Comment: For this question it doesn't matter that the tags are dynamic. It's just XML parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xpathSApply` to fetch node's attributes

```r
library(XML)

doc <- xmlParseDoc("test.xml")
df <- as.data.frame(t(xpathSApply(doc, "//location_tag/location", xmlAttrs)))
```

which gives

```
> df
      country city state
1 SWITZERLAND           
2     URUGUAY
```

**Sample data:** Note that I have slightly modified your sample data as you have not provided complete XML.
`test.xml` contains

```
<location_tag>
<location country="SWITZERLAND" city="" state=""/>
<location country="URUGUAY" city="" state=""/>
</location_tag>
```